# Applying different colors to certain parts of SKLabelNode's text

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, nsattributedstring, sklabelnode

I am pretty much sure that for this can't be used `NSMutableAttributedString` and `NSAttributedString`. What I've tried is:

```
 NSMutableAttributedString * newString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"firstsecondthird"];
    [newString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
    [newString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(5,6)];
    [newString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(11,5)];

labelNode.text = [newString string];
```

This doesn't work and text still has it's original color. Is there any way to do this with `SKLabelNode` ? Using multiple `SKLabelNodes` is solution, but I can't say it's elegant (or performant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 11, SKLabelNode supports NSAttributedStrings, so ASAttributedLabelNode should no longer be necessary. Your code would look like:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * newString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"firstsecondthird"];
    [newString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
    [newString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(5,6)];
    [newString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(11,5)];

labelNode.attributedText = newString;
```

Comment: It's worth noting that not all attributed keys seem to work. The colour ones certainly do, so this answer is quite valid, but I've found that neither underline nor strikethrough function.

Answer (score 4):

I found something that may interest you on GitHub. It's in Swift but code is very short and should be easily comprehensible.

[ASAttributedLabelNode](https://github.com/alex-alex/ASAttributedLabelNode)

Answer (score 2):

`SKLabelNode` does not support `NSAttributedString` or `NSMutableAttributedString`. When you use `labelNode.text = [newString string]` you're taking just the text portion of the attributed string and ignoring all of the changes you made in the previous lines.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yeah, I can see that there is no effect like this, but actually I am interested is there any way to accomplish this with SKLabelNode...Do you have some thoughts on how to do it?

Comment: Since the font is set by its name and the text itself is only accessible via a copy, it looks like there's something happening under the hood where `SpriteKit` manipulates the text as it needs and won't acknowledge attributed text in any way. If you really wanted to , you could probably subclass `SKNode` to replace `SKLabelNode` using an `NSAttributedString` for the `text` property.

Comment: Fennelouski It would be nice if you could write an example for this, even with pseudo code. If not, well it's not a problem :) Anyways, I will upvote your answer for pointing out useful info.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4:

```
let newString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "firstsecondthird")

newString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSMakeRange(0,5))
newString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.green, range: NSMakeRange(5,6))
newString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: NSMakeRange(11,5))

labelNode.attributedText = newString
```